# @Thingsboard I have problem with Thingsboard version 3.4.1

Tags: thingsboard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMv8v.png) When click close on the map (tooltip) how I describe in picture, automatically return to home page. How I can manage it? Can some help me please?

I try to manage it in side thingsboard -> dashboard -> map -> advansed -> tooltip but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED 12.12.2022**

Fix is already available in [3.4.2](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/releases/tag/v3.4.2)

**Old anwer**

It is known bug. [Fixed](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/pull/7181), but not yet released.